# How do I convert some ugly inline JavaScript into a function?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I've got a form with various inputs that by default have no value. When a user changes one or more of the inputs all values including the blank ones are used in the URL GET string when submitted.

So to clean it up I've got some JavaScript that removes the inputs before submission. It works well enough but I was wondering how to put this in a js function or tidy it up. Seems a bit messy to have it all clumped in to an `onclick`. Plus I'm going to be adding more so there will be quite a few.

Here's the relevant code. There are 3 separate lines for 3 separate inputs. The first part of the line has a value that refers to the inputs ID ("mf","cf","bf","pf") and the second part of the line refers to the parent div ("dmf","dcf", etc).

The first part is an example of the input structure:

```
echo "<div id='dmf'><select id='mf' name='mFilter'>";
```

This part is the submit and js:

```
echo "<input type='submit' value='Apply' onclick='javascript: if (document.getElementById(\"mf\").value==\"\") { document.getElementById(\"dmf\").innerHTML=\"\"; }
if (document.getElementById(\"cf\").value==\"\") { document.getElementById(\"dcf\").innerHTML=\"\"; }
if (document.getElementById(\"bf\").value==\"\") { document.getElementById(\"dbf\").innerHTML=\"\"; }
if (document.getElementById(\"pf\").value==\"\") { document.getElementById(\"dpf\").innerHTML=\"\"; }
' />";
```

I have pretty much zero JavaScript knowledge so help turning this in to a neater function or similar would be much appreciated.

Comment: you don't accept answers to questions... i'd be surprised if anyone tries to help.

Comment: Hrm, that is true… I should have noticed that. Well, Taylor, here's your chance!

Comment: @Jason the people that *want* to help will probably help because they are here to help instead of making noise about some piddly statistic that is truly meaningless

Comment: @Josh: True, but the rep and the good feeling of "getting accepted" are both nice :P

Comment: @Josh true, i'm here to help as well. however, helping is a lot easier when your help is appreciated.

Comment: "piddly statistic that is truly meaningless" --- uh...well, from a front end UI and general usability/user experience standpoint, I'd say SO's implementation of the 'piddly statistic' system is rather brilliant. This entire site runs mostly on karma and the implementation is a rather nice model.

Comment: Well, I think its testiment to how great SO is that such a response has come withing 30 minutes of posting. 
@DA - you got it right there, SO is pretty much the best place to come for those head scratching questions and I think the UI and usability is pretty damn good.
Whenever I try doing something on here like voting up, etc it tells me I don't have enough rep? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Jason and David - where the open source spirit of community? I help out people in areas I know about on other forums with no want of any acceptance. I'm not heavy in to programming so I don't use SO that much and am not that aware of my obligations here.

Comment: @Taylor: You should go through your questions and click the hollow check mark next to the best answer for each question to accept that answer.  This will give you enough reputation to vote.

Comment: @SLaks - oh right, the big hollow tick. Hadn't noticed that, lol. Kind of an embarrassingly easy thing to see as well. 
I'll have to go back and tick my previous questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you were to use jquery (and there is no reason not to): 
if your submit button had an id of say id="submit-button" this 'should' work and would handle any additional inputs that get added

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit-button").click(function () {
       $(this).parents("form").find(':input').each(function() {
           if ($(this).val() === "") {
               $(this).innerHTML = "";
           }
       });
    });
});
```

NOTE: I did not test above code at all

here is an updated version

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").submit(function () {
       $(this).find(':input').each(function() {               
           if ($(this).val() === "" && $(this).attr("type") !== "submit") {
               $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
           }
       });
    });
});
```

this one is setting the blank inputs to disabled - I could not get the innerHTML = "" to work on Firefox 3.6 on Mac and I did not test above code on other browsers or OS

you would need to download jquery http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#Current_Release and include a reference to it in your html head

to use the innerHTML trick on the inputs parent span tag change the line $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled'); to

```
if ($(this).parent().get(0).tagName === "SPAN") {
    $(this).parent().get(0).innerHTML = "";                     
}
```

Comment: are you saying this would dynamically ignore the zero value inputs on submission?

Comment: the code finds all inputs in the form that contains the submit button which was clicked and for each input which has a blank value it sets the innerHTML of that input to blank. As long as that innerHTML trick works - then my answer to your question is yes

Comment: Will be great if this works.
think the innerHTML thing doesn't work because the value is within the tag itself and not considered to be the inner HTML. Thats why I ended up wrapping the inputs with a corresponding div.
There are actually some selects as well as inputs if that makes a difference? 

How about having it remove the innerHTML of a span tag with a child that has a zero value (if that makes sense).

html would look something like

[SPAN] [input type=... id="a" value=""]   [/span]

[SPAN] [input type=... id="b" value=""]   [/span]

[SPAN] [select type=... id="c"]   [/span]

Comment: how would I use your code in the context of my code. Is there a function to call in onclick=""?

Comment: no, the document ready bit runs once the page has finished loading and then it automatically binds the function to the form submit event

Comment: updated again - added a few lines that handle when using a parent span tag

and yes this should handle select menu as well, see http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

Comment: I doff my cap to you sir. Just implemented your code using the 'SPAN' and innerHTML change instead of the disabled part and it works brilliantly. It worked straight away without any head scratching and I'll have more use of jquery on my site anyway so including that isn't a big deal. 
DA and David answered my question but you've gone the extra step and provided exactly what I was after. thanks!

Comment: just tried it with the 'disabled' line of code instead of 'innerHTML' trick. That works as well and theres no need for the span tags either.  even better!

Answer (score 7):

your script block in your HEAD:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function yourFunctionName(){
       ...your javascript goes here...
    }
</script>
```

and then your onclick:

```
onclick="javascript:yourFunctionName()"
```

Comment: You can leave off the `javascript:` part of the onclick property. That's only necessary if it's the href on a link.

Answer (score 3):

Seems pretty simple:

```
<script>
function doSubmit() {
    if (document.getElementById("mf").value == "")
        document.getElementById("dmf").innerHTML = "";
    if (document.getElementById("cf").value == "")
        document.getElementById("dcf").innerHTML = "";
    if (document.getElementById("bf").value == "")
        document.getElementById("dbf").innerHTML = "";
    if (document.getElementById("pf").value == "")
        document.getElementById("dpf").innerHTML = "";
}
</script>
<input type="submit" value="Apply" onclick="doSubmit();" />
```

Or you could even get fancy and do something like this:

```
<script>
function doSubmit() {
    var inputs = {
        "mf": "dmf",
        "cf": "dcf",
        "bf": "dbf",
        "pf": "dpf"
    };
    for (var input in inputs) {
        if (document.getElementById(input).value == "")
            document.getElementById(inputs[input]).innerHTML = "";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: That's still ugly.  You could use a string array and a loop.

Comment: Sure, that'd work too. I chose this implementation because, in my experience, it's better to be explicit about things like element names (so that, eg, they are searchable and special cases can easily be handled). But implicit works too.